# Combobox Anidados no ejecutan el evento

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Necesito hacer que un `combobox` dependa de la selección en otro `combobox` sin SQL ni BD. Dejo mi código.

```
private void Paises_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Los países ya están agregados en este combobox.
}

private void Provincias_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Paises.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Argentina")
   {
       Provincias.Items.Add("Buenos Aires");
       Provincias.Items.Add("Santa Fe");
       Provincias.Items.Add("Misiones");
   }
}

private void Capitales_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Paises.SelectedItems.ToString() == "Argentina")
   {
       Capitales.Items.Add("La Plata");
       Capitales.Items.Add("Rosario");
       Capitales.Items.Add("Posadas");
   }
}
```

El problema es que, al ejecutar, selecciono un país en el `combobox` Países y en los otros dos no aparece nada. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Podrias revisar si `Paises.SelectedItems.ToString()` devuelve el valor asignandolo a una variable? tambien puede intentar con `Paises.SelectedValue` o `Paises.Text`

Comment: `Paises.Text` modifica el texto que aparece por defecto en el `combobox`. Por lo tanto, `Paises.SelectedItem.ToStrring()` es el que va.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código esta casi correcto..

En realidad tu problema es que el evento `Paises_SelectedIndexChanged` se ejecuta, pero no hace nada.

Cada uno de esos eventos se ejecuta cuando el componente se lo pide. Y ejecuta su código interno.

Pero vos pusiste el código para llenar el combo provincias, dentro del evento `Provincias_SelectedIndexChanged`, que se ejecuta cuando haces un cambio en el combo provincias, no en el combo paises!

Por lo tanto, lo unico necesario es mover tu codigo al lugar donde va a ser llamado, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
private void Paises_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Paises.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Argentina")
   {
       Provincias.Items.Add("Buenos Aires");
       Provincias.Items.Add("Santa Fe");
       Provincias.Items.Add("Misiones");
   }
    if(Paises.SelectedItems.ToString() == "Argentina")
   {
       Capitales.Items.Add("La Plata");
       Capitales.Items.Add("Rosario");
       Capitales.Items.Add("Posadas");
   }
}

private void Provincias_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void Capitales_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Te recomendaria que leas sobre eventos, y en que momento se ejecutan los mismos

Comment: Y en los otros dos `combobox` pondría un `Items.Clear()` para que, por ejemplo, se muestren las provincias de Argentina en el `combobox` Provincias. Lo mismo con las capitales. Así no se me agrandan tanto los otros dos `combobox`.

Comment: @Unknown6147 Lee sobre eventos.. donde queres agregar el items.clear? para hacer que cosa? asi como esta, cada vez que selecciona algo agrega todas esas cosas al combo. Si, el clear te los va a limpiar si lo pones antes.

Comment: En `Provincias_SelectedIndexChanged` y `Capitales_SelectedIndexChanged`, así no se me amontona todo y me muestra solo capitales y provincias del país seleccionado.

Comment: @Unknown6147 No. seguis sin entender. o sea, que combo vas a vaciar cuando seleccione algo en ese combo? tenes que vaciarlos antes de llenarlos, no al hacer una seleccion sobre ellos. Leiste en que momento se ejecuta cada uno de estos eventos?

Answer (score 2):

Tenes mal acomodadas las funciones de eventos. deberia ser asi.

```
private void Paises_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(Paises.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Argentina")
       {
           Provincias.Items.Add("Buenos Aires");
           Provincias.Items.Add("Santa Fe");
           Provincias.Items.Add("Misiones");
       }
    }

    private void Provincias_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(Paises.SelectedItems.ToString() == "Argentina")
       {
           Capitales.Items.Add("La Plata");
           Capitales.Items.Add("Rosario");
           Capitales.Items.Add("Posadas");
       }
    }

    private void Capitales_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Aca pones lo que pasa cuando se selecciona una capital
    }
```

Comment: en c# no importa el orden de la implementación de los eventos.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver no entendiste la respuesta, es el orden del codigo, la respuesta es igual a la mia y es correcta